# RegEx: Switch from ANSI C++ style open braces (new line) to K&R style (same line as the statement)

Tags: c++, regex, coding-style, reformat

How would you write a regular expression for match and replace in order to reformat C++ code from the *ANSI C++ style*:

```
if (a > 5)
{
}
```

to the *[K&R style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29)*:

```
if (a > 5) {
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `\n[ \t]*\{\n` and replace with `{\n` or with `{\u000D\u000A` if you want to preserve the Windows-style line endings (CR+LF). Note the space in front of the brace for the replace pattern.

Explanation: match a new line followed by series of spaces and/or tabs, an open brace and another new line. Replace with a space, open brace and new line.

Worked with "Quick Replace" in Visual Studio 2010.